# Changing the distance unit from degrees to meters on my semiviriogram in the geostatistical tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image: this is the geostatistical tool]

How can I change my coordinates from decimal degrees to meters?

Comment: I believe it has to be done before you run the wizard.  At least in the DataFrame Properties > Coordinate System, change to a projected coordinate system, and under DataFrame Properties > General, change the units to meters.  It might be even better to re-project your actual data into a distance-based coordinate system.

Comment: @JKelly Thank you for the reply , but i have changed the general units to meters , before i evene imported them, do you think it is because the actual coordinates of the data was imported as decimal degrees rather than meters?

Comment: Yes, that is likely.  If projecting the dataframe didn't help (do make sure you tried that), try running Data Management > Projections and Transformations > Project on your data.  Choose a local coordinate system like a state plane or national grid, or UTM.  Something distance-based.  Then run the wizard on the output of that process.